# Sort operation used more than the maximum 33.5 MB of RAM

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

In Pymongo, I have the following block of code. I would need to bring in all of the data associated with my time search query into memory for further handling. To do that, I use the following block of code.

```
search_query = {"time" : {"$lte" : datetime.datetime.now()}}
search_result = mongo_collection.find(search_query)
ascending_search_result = search_result.sort("time", 1)
oldest_time = ascending_search_result[0]["time"]
descending_search_result = search_result.sort("time",-1)
latest_time = descending_search_result[0]["time"] 
list_search_result = list(search_result)
```

It:

- Searches for the matching records
- Sorts them to find the start and end time points
- Use `list(search_result)` to bring it into memory and convert it into a list

However, when I run `list(search_result)`, the following error is returned.

```
 Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.', 'code': 96, 'codeName': 'OperationFailed'}
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

**Edit** I was wondering if grabbing the items in the search result individually would solve the problem. Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. Same error thrown. I thought this would only bring in one item at a time, which would be the smallest step in importing the records.

```
list_search_result = list()
for item in search_result: 
    list_search_result.append(item)
```

Comment: I think you have 3 options: Shrink your dataset (unlikely), Use a bigger computer (also unlikely), or add indices which will help support the sort operation (has trade-offs) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Comment: Oh I thought that was 32 GB

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully achieve the same thing I wanted to do above with the following. The key is using `aggregate` and `allowDiskUse` option.

```
pipeline = [{"$match" : search_query}]
search_result = mongo_collection.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
list_search_result = list(search_result)

search_result2 = psd_stream_record.find(search_query)
ascending_search_result = search_result2.sort("time", 1)
oldest_time = ascending_search_result[0]["time"]
descending_search_result = search_result2.sort("time",-1)
latest_time = descending_search_result[0]["time"]
```